# \footnote showing a,b,c,d... upto z

Tags: xetex, footnotes

Used the below line of code in xetex the footnote.

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\alph{footnote}}}
```

Output showing

```
u2.22 Sabbath

v2.24 Deu 23.25 

w2.25 1Sa 21.1-6 

x2.26 Lev 24.5-9

y2.27 Deu 5.14

z 3.4 Luk 14.3

3.6 Mat 22.15-16

3.10 Mat 14.36

3.11 Luk 4.41

3.12 Mak 1.34

3.16 Jn 1.42

3.17 Luk 9.54

3.22 Mat 9.34; 10.25
```

a,b,c,d... upto z. afterwards its doesn't showing in `\footnote`

Actually After z ends it should starts aa,ab,ac.....az,ba,bb,bc....bz, likewise..

But now its not working.

Actual output should shows like this

```
u2.22 Sabbath

v2.24 Deu 23.25 

w2.25 1Sa 21.1-6 

x2.26 Lev 24.5-9

y2.27 Deu 5.14

z3.4 Luk 14.3

aa3.6 Mat 22.15-16

ab3.10 Mat 14.36

ac3.11 Luk 4.41

ad3.12 Mak 1.34

ae3.16 Jn 1.42

af3.17 Luk 9.54

ag3.22 Mat 9.34; 10.25
```

Please any one knows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the package `alphalph` with the following declaration:

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\alphalph{\value{footnote}}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{alphalph}  

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\alphalph{\value{footnote}}}}

\begin{document}

\section{Footnotes}

\setcounter{footnote}{25}

Some text\footnote{test} and some more text\footnote{test}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: For the above footnote tag. z,aa,ab.. is working. now I need to insert symbol "^" in all footnotes. How we can do this?

Comment: @Samdoss Do you mean something like `\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\^{}\alphalph{\value{footnote}}}}`

Comment: Yes. But its showing "ˆa1.44 Lev 14.1-32". Actually it is come along with alphebet. I expect "ˆ1.44 Lev 14.1-32"

Comment: \renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textit{\^{}\value{footnote}}}                                      this line is worked correctly. This is the one i expected.